# Extending spring's configuration to hold custom xml settings

Tags: java, spring, configuration

My servlet.xml file holds all my spring configuration related information like datasource bean etc.

```
<bean id="..." class="...">
</bean>
```

Now my application has other settings that I need to save in a configuration file, is it possible to create my own settings in here or is there a better way?

I want something that loads up once and is very fast to reference in my project.

I need this to store some file paths, and other database settings for things like mongodb etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.properties` file:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:///my/cfg.properties"/>
```

If the file contents are:

```
driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
dbname=mysql:mydb
mysetting=42
```

You can reference them in Spring XML like this:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
 <property name="driverClassName"><value>${driver}</value></property>
 <property name="url"><value>jdbc:${dbname}</value></property>
</bean>
```

Reference: [*4.8.2.1 Example: the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`*](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-placeholderconfigurer).

You can also inject these properties into your own classes:

```
@Service
public class MyService {
    @Value("${mysetting}")
    private int mysetting;  //Spring will inject '42' on bean creation

    //...
}
```

Of course you can also use setter-injection like in the example with `DriverManagerDataSource` if you prefer XML.

Also have a look at: [Spring 3.1 M1: Unified Property Management](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/15/spring-3-1-m1-unified-property-management/).

Comment: I want to reference the values from inside my code, not in xml.

Comment: So I do not quite understand your question. I updated my answer (`MyService` example), is it closer to what you want to achieve?

Comment: yes that is what i wanted, so where do I put this .properties file?  can I have multiple ones as you don't seem to be referencing any name to it?  like db.properties or myconfig.properties?